Access one lambda function from another with authentication
I have 2 lambda function.

lambda function with .net core as runtime and auth0 is implemented for authentication.
lambda function with python as runtime.

I am accessing first lambda function is using alb and for second lambda the function URL is created with auth type - AWS_IAM.
I am calling this function URL in first lambda. I have set policy InvokeFunctionUrl to the first lambda function but it is still giving me forbidden error and both the functions are in same account.
Am I missing something?
public async Task<JsonResult> CallLambdaFunction() {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://j34jntbyrfdiuu5h4asek6a63i0topwb.lambda-url.on.aws/");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return new JsonResult(responseBody);
 }


It would help to see the code you are using in the 1st function to invoke the 2nd function. Are you actually making an HTTP request to the function's URL, or are you making an AWS API call to the AWS Lambda Invoke endpoint?

I am using HttpClient's PostAsync method to call function url.

How are you attaching the IAM role of the Lambda function to the HttpClient call? That's not something that happens automatically. Questions on this site that don't include the code needed to reproduce the problem will be closed. You need to edit your question to include the relevant code.

UI have added the code. I am not attaching IAM Role to lambda function call. How can I pass IAM role?

You created the function URL with AWS_IAM authentication, see the description here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html You are then making a completely unauthenticated call to the function URL, which is obviously going to fail since the function URL requires IAM authentication. You should probably not be using a function URL, and just use the AWS SDK to directly perform a Lambda invoke operation instead.
